# Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'

Tags: c++, assembly, mingw, nasm

I have been having issues with compiling a program. I am unsure what these mean and I would be grateful if anyone could help.

```
C:\Users\Joshua\Documents\GitHub\Zeus-TSO\_deps\libmpg123\dct64_sse.S: Assembler
 messages:
C:\Users\Joshua\Documents\GitHub\Zeus-TSO\_deps\libmpg123\dct64_sse.S:41: Error:
 invalid instruction suffix for `push'
C:\Users\Joshua\Documents\GitHub\Zeus-TSO\_deps\libmpg123\dct64_sse.S:46: Error:
 invalid instruction suffix for `push'
C:\Users\Joshua\Documents\GitHub\Zeus-TSO\_deps\libmpg123\dct64_sse.S:449: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `pop'
C:\Users\Joshua\Documents\GitHub\Zeus-TSO\_deps\libmpg123\dct64_sse.S:451: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `pop'
_deps\libmpg123\CMakeFiles\libmpg123_static.dir\build.make:378: recipe for targe
t '_deps/libmpg123/CMakeFiles/libmpg123_static.dir/dct64_sse.S.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]:  [_deps/libmpg123/CMakeFiles/libmpg123_static.dir/dct64_sse.
S.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:225: recipe for target '_deps/libmpg123/CMakeFiles/libmpg12
3_static.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]:  [_deps/libmpg123/CMakeFiles/libmpg123_static.dir/all] Error
 2
Makefile:74: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make:  [all] Error 2
```

Comment: It would really help if you posted the code that this refers to - at least the the lines 41, 46, 449 and 451 - preferrably a couple of lines around it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [x86 Assembly pushl/popl don't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485468/x86-assembly-pushl-popl-dont-work)

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you are trying to build 32-bit assembly code with 64-bit assembler.

You have 2 options:

1. Use 32-bit assembler, for example by utilizing `--32` option;
2. Change code by substituting 64-bit (extended) registers such as `%rax`, for example, instead of 32-bit registers such as `%eax` used with `push`/`pop` instructions.

Since the build system appears to be CMake, I'd refer you to this **[manual](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Assembler)** on how to configure the build for various Assembly dialects in CMake.

You could try:

```
set(CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS "--32")
```

but I haven't tested it.

Comment: I am unsure where to add --32 option. I cannot find a file anywhere that will let me define options for the assembler.

Comment: Updated, have a look.

Comment: Out of curiousity, I changed the Mingw to 32bit and compiled with 32bit. We are now back to the incompatible error.

Comment: Could you provide more information on what exactly are you compiling and what do you want to achieve, otherwise it's difficult to follow what kind of problems you face and even more difficult to propose any solutions.